# Javascript/Jquery stops working after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that works great the first time the form is submitted after that all javascript on the page seems to break. As well as the form won't submit with ajax again.

Here is my ajax call:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true).after('<p class="loading">Searching...</p>');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: pathname,
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    $('#container').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').append(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
  },
});
event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm getting no errors in my console. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Is the response of the AJAX call replacing the original `form` tag?  That would cause the `submit` binding to be lost.

Comment: have you tried using return false instead of event.preventDefault()?

Comment: David not sure what you mean? I don't believe it is. And yeah Jake I actually had it as return false but I was getting the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, the main page content was changing. Which was causing the javascript to unload. So I need to use Jquery .on/.live and then it works. For what ever reason this worked fine on one server and not on another.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `disabled` after submitting the form. And remove the `,` mentioned by @JustinRusso.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true).after('<p class="loading">Searching...</p>');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: pathname,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#container').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').append(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
        $('input:submit').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Didn't notice that comma huh? That's the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below: No Need to define `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true).after('<p class="loading">Searching...</p>');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: pathname,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#container').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').append(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
        $('input:submit').removeAttr("disabled");
      },
    });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: He should use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`, otherwise, his form will submit again, after the `ajax` submission.

Comment: Shouldn't even bother.  Just don't use an 'input type="submit"'  See my answer.

Also, the comma is the actual culprit.

Comment: As I mentioned above I originally had it as a return false, I just tried the preventDefault to see if that mattered. Fixing the comma didn't help either.